# Validating XML - Have one attribute define valid name for other attributes

Tags: xml, xsd

I have an XML structure containing something like this:

```
<goal id="doStuff" .. />
<score goal="doStuff" value="true" points="10" />
```

Works great... until the input became more complex: scores can now rely on multiple goals. We considered:

```
<goal id="doStuff" .. />
<goal id="doOtherStuff" .. />
<goal id="dontDoThis" .. />
<score goal1="doStuff" value1="true" points="10" />
<score goal1="doOtherStuff" value1="true" goal2="dontDoThis" value2="false" points="20" />
```

But there is no limit to the number of goals a score can depend upon, so at some point this format could break. In the end we came up with:

```
<goal id="doStuff" .. />
<goal id="doOtherStuff" .. />
<goal id="dontDoThis" .. />
<score doStuff="true" points="10" />
<score doOtherStuff="true" dontDoThis="false" points="20" />
```

This works for the application itself, but I've been unable to figure out how to write XML Schema to validate this properly; it does not seem possible having valid names for the element defined by another element (I have to admit only having read Part 0 of the XML Schema spec, I only threw a couple Ctrl+Fs at Part 1 and Part 2).

Scores have to be calculated according to rules outside of my control; changing the way goals are defined is not an option for instance. The only flexibility I have is the structure of the XML. Could somebody suggest a way to encode the given structure into XML in such a way it can be validated with XML Schema?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you can modify the structure of your XML freely, you can consider adding the required goals as child elements of scores, like this:

```
<goal id="doStuff" />
<goal id="doOtherStuff" />
<goal id="dontDoThis" />
<score points="10">
  <scoreGoal goal="doStuff" value="true" />
</score>
<score points="20">
  <scoreGoal goal="doOtherStuff" value="true" />
  <scoreGoal goal="dontDoThis" value="false" />
</score>
```

then you can validate your schema, for example:

```
<xs:sequence>
  <xs:element maxOccurs="unbounded" name="goal">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:attribute name="id" type="xs:string" use="required" />
      <!--...-->
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
  <xs:element maxOccurs="unbounded" name="score">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element maxOccurs="unbounded" name="scoreGoal">
          <xs:complexType>
            <xs:attribute name="goal" type="xs:string" use="required" />
            <xs:attribute name="value" type="xs:boolean" use="required" />
          </xs:complexType>
        </xs:element>
      </xs:sequence>
      <xs:attribute name="points" type="xs:int" use="required" />
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
</xs:sequence>
```

PS. I appreciate the element name `scoreGoal` might not be the best choice, but I know nothing about what your data structure represents, so you may want to give it a proper name.

Comment: You're entirely right; should've thought of that myself. :(
Thank you for pointing it out!